# Do short variable declarations lead to poorly structured code in Go?

Tags: coding-style, go, initialization, declaration, package

From looking at a lot of  Go code on GitHub, I have noticed that Go coders love the short variable declaration (`:=`)and use it very often. Here's an example [**Coding Style**](http://mattn.github.io/go-gtk/). But this usage seems far too often to create poorly structured code: Very long functions that bundle lots of functionality together, because  [**Short variable declarations may appear only inside functions.**](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)   If you want to set up a package that encapsulates something akin to a class with members that several short, modularized functions operate on, as good structured programming and OOP practices mandate, you can't really use  short variable declarations effectively for member variables. I tend to get uneasy whenever I see any function that's more than 10 or 15 lines long - I know something's probably not right with that design.

Personally, I'm not a big fan of  short variable declarations except for local initializion of loop counters, etc. Aside from the above mentioned issue, I like to see clearly the type I'm working with. Particularly when looking over new code, short variable declarations assume that the reader knows what the function initializing the variable is returning, or obliges them to go and find out, or deduce it from the context. So, that code becomes less readable and requires the reader to stop, and perhaps search somewhere for its meaning, whereas a`var`declaration might make things immediately clear.

(I suppose one way write better code and still use short variable declarations would be to avoid the use of package global members entirely and parameterize all your functions - not necessarily a bad thing - but this probably creates more work than you will save using short variable declarations.)

As a result I have been opting to use this sort of design for my packages, similar to the way declaration and initialization work in traditional OOP languages such as Delphi and C++:

```
package myPackage

import (
    "importA"
    "importB"
)

var m_member1 *importA.T
var m_member2 *importB.T

func init() {

    m_member1 = new(importA.T)
    m_member2 = new(importB.T)

}
```

Then I have clearly typed, initialized and encapsulated package members that are available for use in the package. Yes, this does violate the good practice of initializing only when necessary, but I don't have to do this in init() either - can do it on an as needed basis, when the member is used for the first time, although that has other potential complications.  (Be that as it may, since initialization of class members in a `constructor` has been common practice for a long time, I don't have much of problem with this, regardless.)

Is this non-idiomatic, "bad" code in Go? Is the abundant use of short variable declarations, with their IMO negative consequences, considered a good thing? Frankly I fail to see how it could be. I tend to think that perhaps short variable declarations are being used too much by programmers who just love the short syntax, and the result is a lot of bloated looking spaghetti style code. Am I missing something?

---

**Edit: Since the question as stated caused a good deal of confusion, I'll try to illustrate with a simple example (this may or may not compile - wrote quickly just to illustrate)**

If I write:

```
package main

import
(
"packageA"
"packageB"
)


func DoStuff(){

    a:=PackageA.T
    a.Dostuff()

    }
```

Then it will be very easy to continue and write:

```
func doStuff(){

    a:=PackageA.T
    b:=PackageB.T
    Dostuff(a)
    DoMorestuff(b)
    DoEvenMorestuff(a,b)
    DoLotsofstuff(a,b)

    .....


    }

func main(){
  DoStuff()
}
```

IMO bundled, bloated, poorly structured code.

> ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

But when I write

```
package main

import

(    "packageA"
    "packageB"
)


var  a packageA.T
var  b packageB.T

init(){

    a=new(packageA.T)
    b=new(packageB.T)

}

Then I can write:

func dostuff(){

    a.Write()

 }

func doMorestuff(){

    b.Write()

 } 


func  doEvenMorestuff(){

  a.Read(b)

  }


func doLotsofstuff(){

 a.ReadWrite(a,b)
 b.WriteRead(b,a)

}

func main(){

  dostuff()
  doMorestuff()
  doEvenMorestuff()
  doLotsofstuff()

}
```

A modularized pipeline style design, which cannot be implemented with the short variable declaration form. The best that can be done using the short form is nested, parameterized functions, which are generally not a very good design choice either.

Some complained that this amounts to globals, but in a well designed, encapsulated package with a minimal public interface, that is no more of an issue than declaring variables local to a function. Packages should be atomic. Member variables have been an accepted component of OOP design "forever" and when used properly, following the rules of OOP and structured programming, they are not globals, but locals to the package or module or class which encapsulates them.

Granted, there is no feature of any language that cannot be used, or abused. My question is simply that short variable declarations seem to be ripe for abuse and force certain design decisions that are less than desirable, unless used very discreetly. I'm asking if there is a way to use the form that will circumvent the issues I have with them and afford me their ease of use without the drawbacks.

**Edit 2:**

---

**Perhaps this is something of a compromise:**

```
package main

import

(    

 "packageA"
 "packageB"

)


  func dostuff(a PackageA.T){

    a.Write()

 }

func doMorestuff(    b PackageB.T ){

    b.Write()

 } 


func  doEvenMorestuff(a a PackageA.T, b PackageB.T ){

  a.Read(b)

  }


func doLotsofstuff(a a PackageA.T, b PackageB.T ){

 a.ReadWrite(a,b)
 b.WriteRead(b,a)

}


func doStackofStuff(){

    a:=PackageA.T
    b:=PackageB.T

    dostuff(a)
    doMorestuff(b)
    doEvenMorestuff(a,b)
    doLotsofstuff(a,b)


}

    func main(){

     doStackofStuff()
```

}

Still bundled up in `main()` but that's not really a complaint - `doStackofStuff()` is my interface call. In "real code" I would write a separate package for all of it, and only  `DoStackofStuff()` would be public and callable from `main()` - the rest would be encapsulated.  The implementation is broken up in `doStackofStuff()`, yet using the short form without nesting.

Comment: this still has *nothing* to do with short declarations. You're just showing 2 different ways of structuring your code. If you need to use globals, go for it.

Comment: _nothing to do with short declarations_ - unless I'm very mistaken, it has everything to with the short form - the short form cannot be global. It has to be declared locally, and is only in scope for the function where it is declared. So, you end up with big fat functions or nested parametrized functions. If I'm just plain mistaken, please correct me.

Comment: The short form is merely a convenience, nothing more. If you can't structure you're code properly, it's not because of the shorthand syntax you're using.

Comment: @JimB - _If you can't structure your code..._ - no argument. It's simply that certain forms facilitate poorly structured code and others facilitate well structured code. But since this is clearly a matter of opinion, and I'm asking them to delete or block this question - too many downvotes. It is closed - no reason to downvote.

Comment: @JimB - _The short form is merely a convenience, nothing more._ I disagree: The short form is only allowed within the context of a function body. That's not just a question of convenience - it means that using it has ramifications in the way your code must be structured. The question contains 3 examples, each with the code structured differently, depending on the use of the short form.

Comment: You are completely inverting the relationship here. You can use the short form where it's valid, but it shouldn't effect how you organize your code on a macro level. You said below you're new to this language; a lot of things make more sense after a few 10s of thousands of LOC. Go write a lot of Go, and I bet when you come back to this it won't matter in the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing a few issues here that are not connected:

1. If you need to emulate classes and structs in Go - don't use modules for them. Use structs. Build "constructors" for them. That's it. I'd hardly even call it emulation, even though it's not 100% identical to C++ or Java classes. I mean, why not just do something like

   ```
   type Foo struct {
       Bar string
       Baz int
   }

   func NewFoo(bar string, baz int) *Foo {
       return &Foo{
           bar,
           baz,
       }
   }

   //and if you want static state - just do this
   var DefaultFoo *Foo

   func init() {
       DefaultFoo = NewFoo("foo", 1)
   }
   ```
2. I don't fully see why doing `:=` inside functions will create spaghetti code. Can you make your point clearer on that? The most harm it can do is scope collisions if you're not careful - like in this example:

   ```
   var x int = 3

   func main() {
       if x == 3 {
           x := 5
           fmt.Println(x) // will print 5
       }

       fmt.Println(x) //will print 3

   }
   ```
3. going back to your example - it's not bad design to import types from a different module (e.g. have a static http client initiated in a module's init() function). But you have to make sure you are really not mixing up responsibility between the two packages.

Comment: OK - I see that you did understand what I'm going for here  and are offering some important information, which I will have to take some time to digest. But: _I don't fully see why doing := inside functions will create spaghetti code_ - that I explained:  _Short variable declarations may appear only inside functions._ Note - I didn't say they **mandate** it, just that they **promote** it. See the example I cited to get a feel for what I mean.

Comment: The API for your linked GTK code seems to enforce initialising a lot of variables. If that's how the library works, you should encapsulate the functionality by creating new types for your application domain. Your example is a demo, which just initializes everything in `main()` and drops it again. Not a good example to critique coding style.

Comment: @comeAndGo the example you link to is just that, an example to demonstrate a lot of the functionallity of the GTK wrapper. Don't read that much into examples. I do not see how this is connected to `:=` though, the example would be just as big if one had to spell out `var .... ` each time too. It's not like [GTK C examples](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.90/x743.html) are that much "prettier".

Comment: @comeAndGo I don't think the problem in the example you mentioned is short variable initialization. This code can be split into several functions, encapsulated around a struct, or given distinct names for local variables. If the code was divided into shorter distinct logic functions, the problem of locality and remembering types and scopes will simply become unimportant.

Comment: @comeAndGo: note that variable declarations outside of functions don't necessarily need to spell out the types.  `var x = "hello"` is a valid way to declare a string variable (both in local and global scope), and gives just as much information as the short form.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer - _ I don't think the problem in the example you mentioned is short variable initialization_ - understood, but see edit. Even if you break it into separate parameterized functions, with the short form they will have to be nested.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer - _It's not like GTK C examples are that much "prettier"._ Understood. Not having worked in any production environment with Go, I see mostly example code from books and stuff on github much of which isn't very pretty... maybe I am not being fair.

Comment: @comeAndGo the last quote isn't mine :) but anyway, I think a good place to find quality Go code is the standard library. It's big but very readable for the most part. You can also check out a couple of my own projects which I think avoid the problems you mentioned. They are not winners of any code beauty contest but they are prettier than that gtk code for sure ;) have a look: https://github.com/dvirsky/GoMR (a toy mapReduce framework) and here  https://github.com/dvirsky/go-pylog (a nice logger emulating python logging)

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer-I looked at go-pylog- that's more like it. _They are not winners of any code beauty contest_ :Regardless, it's some of the nicer looking Go code I've seen out there. I'm still very new with this language-just started messing with it in my spare time over the winter, so I haven't seen much and I'm still working on some of the basics. I worked for many years under a boss who was an incredibly anal design fanatic with an artistic flair-pushed for solutions that were both functional and beautiful - he was very talented... Me, not so much-but I did acquire some of his sensibilities.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge - _var x = "hello"_ I like that form. But I did find that sometimes it doesn't work out quite right, for example if I write `var x = 1` compiler understands I want `int` but I really want `int64`, etc. I suppose I could write `var x = 99999999999999` etc, but just declaring `int64` is easier.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is actually very simple. The only alternative to short variable declaration e.g. `a := 2` is the long variable declaration e.g. `var a int = 2`.

Does either of them promote spaghetti code or make functions inherently longer? No.

Comment: I have to downvote this answer, because it makes no attempt to address the issues explicitly mentioned in the question, but simply states the obvious and makes a proclamation.

Comment: @comeAndGo So does your question - you don't give any rationale for your proclamations.

Comment: @nos - it does now, with examples, (which you are free to reject) and it did before - just not expressed too well - that was my bad.